# How to do pattern matching on string in SML?

Tags: sml

for example，

```
fun f #"a"::_ = "first character is a"
```

But this does not work in sml.
Is there anyway I can do pattern matching on string without turning it to a char list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you forget to include the bracket, so it should be something like this:

```
fun f (#"a"::_) = "first character is a";
```

If you want to do a pattern matching on string, you can use substring directly. In this case, it can be:

```
fun f (str) = if substring(str, 0, 1) = "a" then "first character is a" else ""
```